# Ruby on Rails method that updates the value of a variable being activated from the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method called "renew" in my controller(using helper_method) that will add 30 days to the variable "subscription." I have a button in the view to call the method, but when I click the button, nothing seems to work.

Here is the controller and the view snippets..

posts_controller.rb

```
   def renewal!
    @post.expiration = @post.expiration + 30.days
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
        <td><%= button_to 'Renew', :action => 'renewal' %>
```

UPDATE:

routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks"}

  root 'posts#index'
  get '/posts/owner', to: 'posts#owner'
  get 'search', to: 'posts#search'


  resources :posts do
    member do
      post 'renewal'
      end
  end
```

Comment: Your action is called `renewal!`, and you invoke `renewal`. You're writing to Cathryn but your friend is Catherine.

Answer (score 0):

```
(<%= button_to "Renew", { :controller => "posts", :action => "renewal"} %>)

# routes.rb

get "posts/renewal" => "posts#renewal
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First, the routing. A `button_to` will result in a `POST` request.

```
resources :posts do
    member do
      post 'renewal'
    end
  end
```

Next, use the same action name and save the record too.

```
  def renewal
    @post.expiration = @post.expiration + 30.days
    @post.save
  end
```

Comment: im getting this error "No route matches {:action=>"renewal", :controller=>"posts"}"

Comment: Post your config/routes.rb.

Comment: In log/development.log, look for the routing error line and see what it says.. it should look something like this: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [XXX] "/posts/1/renewal"): ...`

Answer (score 0):

**routes.rb**

```
resources :posts do
    member do
      patch :renew
    end
  end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_post,
    only: %i[renew]

  def renew
    @post.increment! :expiration, 30.days
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post ||= Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Renew', [:renew, post], method: :patch %></td>
```

Comment: I tried this and got, "undefined method `renew_path' "

Comment: That must mean that @post is nil in your index view. Can we see the rest of the index template?

Comment: @warchildx3 I'm assuming since you're looping over many posts that you're variable is called `post` and not `@post`. Try my updated code.

Comment: so I tried your update, and Im getting "undefined method `increment!' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: That's because `@post` is `nil`. I've update my answer